# RabbitMQ brake the loop on SIGINT

Tags: php, rabbitmq, signals

I use rabbitMQ exactly like manual shows ([manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html)).

```
while(count($this->channel->callbacks)) {
    $this->channel->wait();
}
```

But when I want to terminate my worker I press Ctrl + c in console, the worker gets the SIGINT signal. The problem is that if there are no messages in a queue, the $channel->wait()  method never comes to next iteration, thus it can't be terminated unless I kill it with kill -9. So how can I terminate this endless loop with SIGINT?